# Difference between 반 and 수업?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, pronunciation, word-usage

What is the difference between 반 and 수업 ?

Do they both mean class?

Answer (score 2):

반 and 수업 mean different things that happen to correspond to the English word "class."

반 is a group of students who share the same classroom - they go to the same room every morning, have the same designated teacher (담임), and get the same classes throughout the day.  (This is different from, say, American high schools, where every student has their own schedule and takes each class in a different room.)  It's a system used throughout elementary/middle/high schools: depending on the context, "room" might be a better translation for this concept.  E.g., "저는 3학년 2반이에요." = "I'm in the 3rd grade, room #2."

수업 is the act of taking a class: i.e., students sit in a classroom, the teacher arrives, teaches a given subject for a designated time slot, and then the teacher (usually) leaves.  E.g., "오늘 영어 수업은 참 어려웠다." = "Today's English class was quite difficult."